# Ajax stay loading after succes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to build a code that sends data via "post" to add them to the data of purchase order of Woocommerce with this code..

```js
  jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function(){
   jQuery.ajax({
    data: sendJsonA, //This is the info to send
    url:ajaxurl,
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    beforeSend: function(){
     console.log('Sending')//Muestra el objeto enviado
    },
    success: function(response){
     console.log('Success ) //Muestra e
    }
   })
   .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
      console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente.");
    return
   })
   .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
     console.log( "La solicitud a fallado 2: " +  textStatus+"----------------");
    return
   }); 
   return        
  })
```

This receive the data

```html
 add_action('wp_ajax_ele_inSelectionGrid', 'ele_inSelectionGrid');
 function ele_inSelectionGrid()
 {
  session_start();
  $customData                 =$_POST['data'];

  $_SESSION['data']     =$customData;

  unset($_POST['data']);
  die();
  return;
 };
```

This part of the code runs well, however every time the success message is executed the page is loaded and does not advance to the cart page until the chrome button is given to "interrupt the loading of this page" and click again to buy and go to the cart page with the information sent correctly .. I am new programming so I appreciate any additional comments, thank you very much

I was thinking that the problem had to do with the event click on the buy button, since my ajax script is executed with the click click on that button, besides the buy event of the same button, then two http requests are generated at the same time with the same event click, but I have no idea how to make my script continue the normal loading of the page after ajax completes the sending of the data

Comment: Have you looked at the browser console to check for errors?

Comment: Yes, and nothing is show except the message of XHR Loaded and the console.log that i write in .success of ajax

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but a point of note. If you add a `$` in the right place, you can then you the `$` in front of your jQuery statements instead of using jQuery.whatever.

`jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').click(function($){ 
     //now you can prepend your jQuery statements with $
    $("#element_id").text(); //or whatever
});`

Comment: Thank you! I will keep it in mind..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `done` and `fail` methods,  use the `completed` and `error` ajax closures after each request.

```
jQuery.ajax({
            data: sendJsonA, //This is the info to send
            url:ajaxurl,
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                console.log('Sending')//Muestra el objeto enviado
            },
            success: function(response){
                console.log('Success') //Muestra e
            },
            completed:function (data, textStatus){
                if ( console && console.log ) {
                console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente.");
               }
            },
            error:function (){
                console.log('Could not connect');
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the asnwer i looking for